# Linq - Get the Index of the Last Non-Zero Number of Array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

Is there a Linq expression that returns the index of the last non-zero value in an array? I'm not interested in an extension, only a simple linq expression.

I'm imagining something like this pseudo code:

```
int index = {0, 2, 1}.LastOrDefaultAt(i => i > 0);
```

The returned value should be 2;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.FindLastIndex<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5s03t6d.aspx) method for this:

```
int index = Array.FindLastIndex(myIntArray, item => item > 0);
```

I notice that you mention "non-zero" rather than "greater than zero" in your question text. Should your predicate be: `item => item != 0` ?

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks. This brings up the issue of why doesn't Intellisense show FindLastIndex if I type "myIntArray." -- it shows many other methods. It does show if I type "Array.".

Comment: Because it's a static method on the `Array` class; not an instance method.

Comment: Ah. Thanks again. Seems like there should be some way for Intellisense to give developers a clue that additional static methods are available. I just spent a few hours on something that Intellisense could have helped prevent.

Comment: that's where extension methods come into play

Answer (score 4):

`List<T>` has an extension method for this called `FindLastIndex`

```
var index = new int[] { 0, 2, 1}.ToList().FindLastIndex(x => x > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] index = { 0, 2, 1 };

        var query = from p in index
                    where p != 0
                    orderby p descending
                    select p;

        Console.WriteLine(query.FirstOrDefault());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output: 2. Could be written in method syntax if desired:

```
var index = new int[] { 0, 2, 1 }.Where(a => a != 0).OrderByDescending(a => a).FirstOrDefault();
```