# How do I find how many of a given number there are in an array of ints?

Tags: c#

I have an array of ints.

```
arrayOfInts = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0 };
```

How can I determine how many of a given number there are in this array? For example, how do I determine how many 0s there are in this array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we find items count in the C# integer array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906471/how-can-we-find-items-count-in-the-c-sharp-integer-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer without linq.

```
int count = 0;

foreach (int item in arrayOfInts)
{
  if (item == 0) count++;
}
```

This is a simple example of looping through each element to increment a counter

Answer (score 3):

here is an answer using Linq.

```
var answer = arrayOfInts.Count(i => i == 0)
```

This will count the number of times the function argument returns true for each element in the collection. So if you want to count occurrences of another condition, you just change the function being evaluated in Count().

Answer (score 1):

you can use linq to find each number count

```
var obResult = (from arr in arrayOfInts
               group arr by arr 
               into grp
               select new
               {
                 Value = grp.Key,
                 Total = grp.Count()
               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an even simpler way:

```
Var nmbrOfElements = arrayOfInts.length;
```

A simple way to check or print the length.

- on console.

  ```
   Console.WriteLine("number of elements in array: "+nmbrOfElements);
  ```
- on messagebox.

  ```
  Messagebox.show(nmbrOfElements.ToString());
  ```

Comment: this does not answer the OP's question.  OP wants to know the count of a given occurrence, not the length of the array